# Programatically Login http://waec2013.com/waecexam/ in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping

Guys I try to login to http://waec2013.com/waecexam/ website by using

1. HttpWebRequest
2. CookieContainer

There is another technique I can use webbrowser but as this is web application so I cannot use webbrowser.
But no luck is this possible that I can login to that website and get the specific data?

I do reverse engineering and do some coding but not achieve my result.

Any Suggestions

```
     string formUrl = "http://waec2013.com/waecexam/"; 
     string formParams = string.Format("adminName={0}&adminPass={1}&act={2}",
     "passwaec", "cee660","login");
     string cookieHeader;
     WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
     req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     req.Method = "POST";
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
     req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
     using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
     {
         os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     }
     WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
     cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

     string pageSource;
     string getUrl = "http://waec2013.com/waecexam/Leads.php";
     WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
     getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
     WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
     {
        pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Use fiddler to examine/reverse eningeer all http trafic and then buildup again with the technique you already discovered.

Comment: Any Example That can help me

Comment: From the above code I didn't get the cookie value, it returns me null

Comment: Still didn't get anything, I am stuck here can you plz try this function and get any result, its really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have resolve my own question and post for you guys if you need it.

```
 public class CookiesAwareWebClient : WebClient
 {
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    public CookiesAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
  }

   using (var client = new CookiesAwareWebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "adminName", "passwaec" },
            { "adminPass", "cee660" },
            { "x", "0" }, 
            { "y", "0" }, 
            { "act", "login" },
        };

        // We authenticate first
        client.UploadValues("http://waec2013.com/waecexam/index.php", values);

        // Now we can download
        client.DownloadFile("http://waec2013.com/waecexam/leadExp.php?act=export",
        @"c:\abc.txt");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the start of your method:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
```

After each line where you create a webrequest assing the cookies to the instantiated request:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

This will store any incoming cookies and send all cookies in the container to the webserver when GETing POSTing.

You don't need to use the Set-Cookie header in that case.

Comment: Still did'nt get any result, I try my level best, may be I have some understanding issue. Can you plz try above code and correct me.